# How can I create a new binary variable that categorizes people based on if they EVER had a certain response in the dataset?

Tags: r

I'm examining drug use over 5 years in about 100 people. I want to create a binary variable that indicates whether people could *ever* be considered drug users (0=never user, 1=user).

Below, 1 indicates drug use, 0 indicates none, and NA indicates missing data at that time. Here are some example cases:

```
0  0  0  1  1
0  1  0  1  1
NA 0  1  0  NA
NA 0  0  0  1
0  0  NA NA 0
```

Almost all of my cases have missing data for at least one time point.

I'm new to R so I'm really struggling to figure out how to create this new binary variable. Basically the code needs to scan all 5 time points to see if a "1" ever appears, and it needs to be able to handle NAs.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: do you need to check across rows or columns, i.e. are individuals the rows or the columns?

Comment: whoops, just realized I pasted 5 cases...that was confusing of me! cases are rows; time points are columns. so i need to check all the responses along each row. About to try the answers just posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df1$new <- +(rowSums(df1 == 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, if the data had 50 million columns, using any would stop at the first occurrence whereas using sums would use all of the data?

Comment: @desval If you are using `any` with `apply`, it is looping over rows and that would not be efficient, while `rowSums` is vectorized.

Comment: @desval another option is `Reduce(`|`, df1)` as it is binary.  But,you may have to remove the `NA`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the individuals show up on the rows, and the years as columns:

```
  d <- read.table(text="
      0  0  0  1  1
    0  1  0  1  1
    NA 0  1  0  NA
    NA 0  0  0  1
    0  0  NA NA 0", header=F
    )

d$true <- apply(d,1, function(x)any(x==1, na.rm = T))*1

d

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 true
1  0  0  0  1  1    1
2  0  1  0  1  1    1
3 NA  0  1  0 NA    1
4 NA  0  0  0  1    1
5  0  0 NA NA  0    0
```